# How to use pnp-js at a node.js application to fetch data from sharepoint?

Tags: node.js, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, pnp-js

I got a node.js application and I'm trying to use the AdalFetchClient of PnPjs to fetch some data from sharepoint.

```
sp.setup({
  sp: {
    baseUrl: "https://placeholder.sharepoint.com",
    fetchClientFactory: () => {
      return new AdalFetchClient("tenantId", "azure_clientId", "azure_clientSecret");
    },
  },
});

await sp.web.getAppCatalog().get();
```

**I get this error: `Error making HttpClient request in queryable [401] Unauthorized ::> {"error_description":"Invalid issuer or signature."}`**

I setup the permissions of my azure active directory app like so:
[Azure App permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBT94.png)

I granted all the permissions to the tenant I'm trying to fetch data from:
[Granted permissions to Azure App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb4ll.png)

The example I used is here: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/nodejs/adal-fetch-client/
I also tried to use the AdalFetchClient with graph.. which is working. Only the sharepoint api seems to have a problem.

Comment: Did you configure a self-signed X.509 certificate in your Azure AD app by following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread?

Comment: I actually didn't! Thanks for this resource. Do you know how to add the certificate to the AdalFetchClient of pnp-js? I really dont want to use powershell to be honest. :D

Comment: Or do you know how to send the certificate as http header?

Comment: I have no idea. I think you should follow the official document.

Comment: Please keep posted to let me know if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There is a AdalCertificateFetchClient which requires the following paramters:

- Tenant-ID
- Azure App Client ID
- Thumbprint of your x.509 certificate
- The private key of your x.509 certificate
- The root url of the sharepoint you want to connect to

So first of all you have to create a x.509 certificate. I used [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) for this. (Thanks for that)

After that you have to get your thumbprint by installing the certificate to your local machine and following [this steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in)

Last step is to get your private key of your certificate. For that you have to install openssl for windows and follow [this steps](https://dzone.com/articles/extract-crt-amp-key-file-from-pfx-file-in-a-minute)

Now you can use your AdalCertificateFetchClient